# Show that if the inverse cumulative distribution function is continuous, it is invertible

Tags: probability-theory, quantile, cumulative-distribution-functions, quantile-function

Let $F:\mathbb R\to[0,1]$ be a distribution function$^1$ and note that $$F^{-1}(t):=\inf\left\{x\in\mathbb R:F(x)\ge t\right\}\;\;\;\text{for }t\in(0,1)$$ is left-continuous and nondecreasing with $$F^{-1}(t)\le x\Leftrightarrow t\le F(x)\;\;\;\text{for all }x\in\mathbb R\text{ and }t\in(0,1)\tag1.$$

> **Question 1**: Let $t\in(0,1)$. How can we show that if $F$ is continuous at $x:=F^{-1}(t)$, then $F(x)=t$?
>
> **Question 2**: Now let $F_1,F_2$ be distributions functions, $s\in(0,1)$ and $x:=F_1^{-1}(s)$. Assume $x\in F_2^{-1}((0,1))$. I want to determine a $t\in(0,1)$ such that $F_2^{-1}(t)=x$. I guess we need to distinguish whether $F_2$ is continuous at $x$ (in which case there should be a unique solution) or not (in which case there should be an solution interval).

I guess both questions are easy to prove, but somehow I've got problems to solve them. Regarding the first question: I've tried to assume the contrary, i.e. $\varepsilon:=|F(x)-t|>0$, but I wasn't able to derive a contradiction from that.

Regarding the second question: In the first question we've shown that if $(F\circ F^{-1})(t)=t$ for all $t\in(0,1)$ such that $F$ is continuous at $F^{-1}(t)$. Now I guess that we need to show something similar: If $F$ is continuous at $x\in\mathbb R$, then $(F^{-1}\circ F)(x)=x$.

With this result we would see that if $F_2$ is contiunous at $x:=F_1^{-1}(s)$, then we may choose $t=(F_2\circ F_1^{-1})(s)=F_2(x)$.

---

$^1$ i.e. $F$ is right-continuous and nondecreasing with $F(-\infty):=\lim_{x\to-\infty}F(x)=0$ and $F(\infty):=\lim_{x\to\infty}F(x)=1$.

Comment: Is the interval on the RHS of $(2)$ meant to be defined using $F_2$ instead of $F$?

Comment: @RhysSteele Yes, sure!

Answer (score 1):

**Question 1:** Let $x_0 = F^{-1}(t)$. Since $F$ is continuous at $x_0$, $$\lim_{n \to \infty} F(x_0 - n^{-1}) = F(x_0) = \lim_{n \to \infty} F(x_0 + n^{-1})$$

Since $x_0 - n^{-1} < x_0$ we have that $F(x_0 - n^{-1}) < t$ so that $\lim_{n \to \infty} F(x_0 - n^{-1}) \leq t$. Also, by definition of $x_0$, for every $n$ there is an $x_1 < x_0 + n^{-1}$ such that $F(x_1) \geq t$. Since $F$ is non-decreasing we have that $F(x_0 + n^{-1}) \geq t$ and so $\lim_{n \to \infty} F(x_0 + n^{-1}) \geq t$. Combining this we have that $t \leq F(x_0) \leq t$ which implies the desired result.

**Question 2:** [This part of the answer was written before the assumption $x \in F_2^{-1}((0,1))$ was added, which invalidates it]

This result is false (assuming the $F$ on the right hand side is meant to be one of $F_1$ or $F_2$). For example let $F_1$ be the distribution function of a uniform random variable on $[0,1]$ and $F_2$ be the distribution function of the constant random variable $0$. Then for any $t \in (0,1)$, we have that $F_2^{-1}(t) = 0$. However, e.g. $F_1^{-1}(\frac12) = \frac12$ so we can set $x = \frac12$. We then have that
$$\{ t \in (0,1): F_2^{-1}(t) = x\} = \emptyset \neq \{1\} = \{F_2(\frac12)\}   = [F_2(\frac12 -), F_2(\frac12+)]$$

We also have that $\emptyset \neq \{F_1(\frac12)\} = \{\frac12\}$.

---

For the current formulation of question $2$, you can always take $t = F_2(x)$. Indeed, if $y \geq x$ then $F_2(y) \geq F_2(x) = t$ so that $F_2^{-1}(t) \leq x$. If $F_2^{-1}(t) < x$ then there is $x_1 < x$ such that $F_2(x_1) \geq t = F_2(x)$. Since $F_2$ is non-decreasing this means that $F_2$ is constant on $[x_1,x]$. But then $x \not \in F_2^{-1}((0,1))$ since if $x \in \{y : F_2(y) \geq t_0\}$ then $x_1 \in \{y: F_2(y) \geq t_0\}$ also.

Comment: Sorry, but how do you conclude $F(x_0-n^{-1})\le t$ from $x_0-n{-1}\le x_0$? The latter clearly implies $F(x_0-n^{-1})\le F(x_0)$ though.

Comment: If $F(x_0 - n^{-1}) \geq t$ then $x_0$ can't be $F^{-1}(t)$ by the definition of $F^{-1}(t)$ as an $\inf$

Comment: Sure, you are right. Missed the definition for a moment.

Comment: Please take note of my edit. I've reformulated question 2.

Comment: @0xbadf00d It's quite frustrating to have you edit a question once I've answered in a way that changes the validity of my answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, that was not my intention.Your answer is still valid for question 1. And, actually, question 2 is still the same. I just realized that I made some mistakes in phrasing it.

Comment: It should still be the same question: If $F_2$ is continuous at $x$, the unique solution should be $t=(F_2\circ F_1^{-1})(s)=F_2(x)$ and otherwise the solution interval should be $\left[\lim_{y\to x-}F_2(y),\lim_{y\to x+}F_2(y)\right]$, which is precisely what I've asked for before. My feeling was that you've misunderstood the former formulation (maybe due to the typos).

Comment: I've decided to add an edit that answers your new formulation. I hope that you do not decide to edit to ask a different question again.

Comment: Thank you for your edit. I think we need to extend the definition of $F_2^{-1}$ to the endpoints of $[0,1]$ then, since $t$ could be $0$ or $1$. I'm not sure if I get your argument that "if $y\ge x$, then $F_2(y)\ge F_2(x)=t$ so that $F_2^{-1}(t)\le x$". Your conclusion $F_2^{-1}(t)\le x$ doesn't depend on $y$ and, in fact, $F_2^{-1}(t)\le x$ should trivially follow from the definition $t=F_2(x)$ and $(1)$ (which clearly holds for $t=0$ and $t=1$ as well). Did you intend to define $t:=F_2(x)$ at all? I guess not, since $F_2^{-1}(t)<x$ is then clearly impossible.

Comment: Ignore the last sentence; for some reason I wrote $F_2^{-1}(t)<x$ but got $F_2^{-1}(t)>x$ in my mind.

Comment: However, I still can't follow. Clearly, if $x_0\in\mathbb R$ and $t:=F(x_0)$, then (since $F$ is nondecreasing) $$M_t:=\{x\in\mathbb R:F(x)\ge t\}=\{x\ge x_0:F(x)\ge F(x_0)\}\uplus\{x<x_0:F(x)=F(x_0).$$ So, if $F^{-1}(t)<x_0$, the set on the right-hand side of the union cannot be empty and hence there is a $x_1<x_0$ with $F(x)=F(x_0)$ for all $x\in[x_1,x_0]$ which in turn implies $[x_1,x_0]\subseteq M_t$. Now if $x_0\in F^{-1}([0,1])$, there is a $t_0\in[0,1]$ with $x_0=F^{-1}(t_0)$ which implies $x_0\in M_{t_0}$ and hence $x_1\in M_{t_1}$ which is a contradiction, since $x_1<x_0=\inf M_{t_0}$

Comment: @0xbadf00d The argument you mention in the first of your most recent comments is exactly the argument by which it follows that $F_2^{-1}(t) \leq x$ (Or I guess that establishes your $(1)$). The $y$ appears implicitly in $F_2^{-1}(t) = \inf \{y : F(y) \geq t\}$ since I really mean the $y$ in that set. However as long as you believe the claim that $F_2(t) \leq x$, this doesn't really matter. This is just a direct argument from the definition for that that doesn't go through $(1)$.

Comment: I am confused by your most recent comment. You say you can't follow but then give an absolutely correct (if a little lengthy) restatement of the argument I made in my answer to show that we cannot have $F_2^{-1}(t) < x$ (or $x_0$ in your notation). What exactly is the remaining problem?

Comment: Everything is clear now. I just wasn't sure how you defined some of your symbols. However, I'd still be interested in the characterization of the solution interval, but since I guess this was still not clear from my formulation I've asked a separate question for that: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3499093/47771.

Answer (score 0):

Question 1: Let $x^+_n$ be a sequence approaching $x$ from above, (and $x^-_n$ approach from below). We will make none of them equal to $x$; just that the limits of these two sequences are $x$. It is easy to see that $F(x^+_n) \geq t$, since by definition, $x$ is a lower bound for all $x_i$s that satisfy that property, and $F$ is monotone non-decreasing. Similarly, we have that $F(x^-_n) \leq t$, since if for any $x^-_n < x$ was greater than $t$, $x$ could not be the infimum (we are invoking monotonicity here again). Taking limits now gives you what you want.

Question 2: (I don't really understand why you have $F_1$ and $F_2$ there; I am taking them both equal to $F$) If the upper and lower limits are different, you actually need to make the lower limit an open bracket: Take $F$ to be a half step at 0 and another half step at 1, and let $x$ equal to $1$. The limit of $F(x)$ approaching $1$ from the bottom will be 1/2, but $F^{-1}(1/2)$ is not 1. Besides that I think the above proof mostly goes through.

Note: I was actually writing a proof claiming the claim was correct; I stopped after getting stuck only to realize the claim was incorrect. I am leaving it behind as a potential reference to writing out the proof of the second claim (might get back to it later if there is demand, or if someone wants to pick it up from there on)

<del>Question 2: Yes to both claims (though I don't really understand why    you have $F_1$ and $F_2$ there; I am taking them both equal to $F$).    We need to show that the two sets contain each other. Let $t$ be such    that $F^{-1}(t) = x$. The proof is essentially the same as last part,    where you get $F(x^+_n) \geq t$ and $F(x^-_n) \leq t$, so $t$ is    between those limits. 
       Now, just run the arguments backwards; i.e. conversely, take a $t$    between those limits, then $t$ satisfies those two individual    inequalities. Now, we invoke the fact that $x$ is indeed the inverse    of some $s$, (the statement would fail in flat regions of $F$    otherwise). 
       Note that $x$ is the best lower bound for $F^{-1}(s)$, and so is also    the best lower bound for all $t$ in the interval. Suppose not.    Suppose that there is a different $x'$ for some other $t$ in the    interval; this $x'$ is either bigger or smaller than $x$. If $t > s$,    then $x' > x$, however, we know that there exists a sequence $x^+_n$    that gets arbitrarily close to $x$ that satisfies $F(x^+_n) \geq t$,    so $x'$ cannot be the lower bound. 
       The other case $t < s$ is surprisingly more complicated.</del>

Comment: Please take note of my edit. I've reformulated question 2.